# Hibernate - How to provide right mapping to integer type?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

I'm executing my maven build and it throws this exception:

`Last cause: Wrong column type in x.clients for column type. Found: tinyint, expected: integer`

I'm mapping like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
```

And I'm creating the column using InnoDB like this: `id int NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT`

Shouldn't this be ok? Why is it saying that he is finding tinyint?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Wicket, can you please remove the "wicket" tag?

Comment: Let me show your Client entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [@Basic](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property) for basic integers. You can always trying declaring your ID as a Long though. I usually always use Long for my IDs. See [Mapping Identifier Properities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

Comment: Well, setting the id as Long actually did the trick. But for some reason I can't use a tinyint on an Integer. Ah well.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is (really!) old, but:

TINYINT represents 8-bit values. It's mapped to byte/Byte. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive) in both cases.

SMALLINT represents 16-bit values. It's mapped to short/Short.

INTEGER represents 32-bit values. It's mapped to int/Integer.

BIGINT represents 64-bit values. It's mapped to long/Long.

So, you can't map a tinyint using an Integer; you must use a Byte.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: why do you suggest a tinyint map to a Byte and not a Short?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the type annotation:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.IntegerType")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this problem and it should be useful to share the details. What was happening in my case is:

- you define @Column (... definition = "integer" )
- Oracle translated 'integer' into decimal(0,-127) (or decimal(0), I haven't it clear)
- You use some other application where 'test.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' is 'validate'
- Hibernate reports that integer != decimal and validation fails

my only solution has been to keep test.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto empty (undefined = the DB is not touched). Not sure whether it's an Oracle or Hibernate bug (or both).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the annotations for the `id` field:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
```

Comment: Still giving me the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "int")
```

Comment: Still giving me the same exception.