# Hibernate : Could not determine type for: Integer

Tags: java, hibernate

I get an error saying `Could not determine type for: Integer, at table: t_credential, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(id)]` when running the program.

My t_credential database has a PK column `id` which is set by the application ( not auto increment).

Here's my XML mapping file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

 <class name="com.x.com.core.pojo.TUIDInfo" table="t_pop3_credential_messageuid">
   <id name="id" column="id" type="integer" >
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
    <property name="messageUID"><column name="messageUID" /></property>
     <many-to-one name="cred" column="credential_id" class="com.x.listener.core.imap.Credential" ></many-to-one>
     </class>

     <class name="com.x.listener.core.imap.Credential" table="t_credential" >
        <id name="id" column="id" type="Integer" >
            <generator class="select" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="email" type="String" length="100"   />
        <property name="password" column="password" type="String" length="100"   />
        <property name="mailServer" column="mail_server" type="String" length="100" />
        <property name="protocol" column="protocol" type="String" length="100"  />
        <property name="tenant" column="tenant" type="String"  />
        <property name="host" column="host" type="String" length="100"  />  
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My TUID Class :

```
package com.x.com.core.pojo;

import com.x.listener.core.imap.Credential;

public class TUIDInfo {

    private Integer id;
    private String messageUID;// change accordingly
    private Credential cred;



    public TUIDInfo( String messageUID, Credential cred) {
        super();

        this.messageUID = messageUID;
        this.cred = cred;

    }

    public TUIDInfo() {
        super();
    }

    public Integer getid() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setid(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessageUID() {
        return this.messageUID;
    }

    public void setMessageUID(String messageUID) {
        this.messageUID = messageUID;
    }
    public Credential getCred() {
        return this.cred;
    }

    public void setCred(Credential cred ) {
        this.cred = cred;
    }

}
```

and My Credential Class:

```
package com.x.listener.core.imap;
public class Credential {
    Integer id;
    private String host;// change accordingly
    private String username;
    private String password;// change accordingly
    private String mailServer;
    private String protocol;
    private String tenant;


    public Credential(Integer id, String host, String username,
            String password, String mailServer, String protocol, String tenant) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.host = host;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.mailServer = mailServer;
        this.protocol = protocol;
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    public Credential() {
        super();
    }

    public String getProtocol() {
        return protocol;
    }

    public void setProtocal(String protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getMailServer() {
        return mailServer;
    }

    public void setMailServer(String mailServer) {
        this.mailServer = mailServer;
    }

    public String getTenant() {
        return tenant;
    }

    public void setTenant(String tenant) {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    public void setProtocol(String protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

}
```

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149874/hibernate-how-to-provide-right-mapping-to-integer-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change it to lower case:

```
<class name="com.x.listener.core.imap.Credential" table="t_credential" >
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer" >  <!-- Instead of Integer -->
            <generator class="select" />
        </id>
```

as you're using above in:

```
<class name="com.x.com.core.pojo.TUIDInfo" table="t_pop3_credential_messageuid">
   <id name="id" column="id" type="integer" >
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. Foolish of me.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `type="Integer"` and `type="String"`.
The `type` attribute holds the hibernate mapping type, this mapping types will convert from Java to SQL data type.
In your case you can use `type="int"` or `type="string"`.