# Spring Boot with JPA - wrong column type encountered in column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot Starter Data Jpa (2.1.9.RELEASE) and I'm trying to map this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `woo` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The Entity is mapped as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "woo")
    private Integer woo;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getWoo() {
        return woo;
    }

}
```

When I start the application I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [woo] in table [foo]; found [tinyint (Types#TINYINT)], but expecting [integer (Types#INTEGER)]
```

My properties are:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:///test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

I tried to do the same mapping using vanilla Jpa and Hibernate (not managed by Spring) and it works fine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[Here's a link to the maven project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yphzq8x76p0etva/spring-test.zip?dl=0), in case anyone want to try it directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate - How to provide right mapping to integer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149874/hibernate-how-to-provide-right-mapping-to-integer-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to override the default JDBC type Hibernate using an explicit type declaration:

```
@Column(name = "woo", columnDefinition = "TINYINT(4)")
private Integer woo;
```

This should fix.

Comment: I was able to use an Integer type with this property, but only when I removed this property from my application.properties file

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers: true

Answer (score 3):

Your database is using a TinyInt, while your class is making it expect an integer. TinyInt maps to byte however, which is where the confusion is taking place.

```
@Column(name = "woo")
private Byte woo;
```

A reference for mapping types can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_types.htm).

Comment: Then why if I make a simple java project using JPA + Hibernate (same versions of the one managed by spring) it works flawlessly without adding extra annotations?

Comment: I really do not know if I am being honest with you. Spring Data just provides a layer of abstraction that tries to make doing things easier and with less boilerplate code, but it is not a JPA provider itself (hence why it comes with hibernate). Hibernate attempts to map the data type from the database and the datatype from Java and match them with its own hibernate type, resulting in a mismatch if they do not result in the same hibernate type. Everything that I can find however, states that Hibernate will map TinyInt to Byte/byte.

Comment: My above comment can be further seen here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/type/package-summary.html . The types are compared using the interface found here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/type/Type.html . If it is possible, maybe you could attempt to debug to see what is happening under the hood and notice any differences that may be occurring between the two. Unless there is a change in the mapping or some weird data conversions happening under the hood (possible String conversions?), I cannot think of what the reason may be.

Comment: If you do figure out the specific reason, post a comment back stating what it was if you can - I'm fairly curious myself.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, I think that maybe some configuration that defaults in a way in Spring has another default in vanilla Hibernate.
I'll try to investigate more as soon as I have a little more free time.

Answer (score 2):

JDBC tinyint equivalent Java type is Byte.
Here is the hibernate documentation. [Datatype mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch03.html#basic-provided)

JBoss tool will be helpful if you are using eclipse/STS to generate entities directly from the tables without datatype conflict.